# Call swagger web service with c#

Tags: c#, api, web-services, swagger, swagger-ui

I have swagger web service URL with get and delete methods.

I want to write code to retrieve data from swaggers web service.

I already installed package **Swashbuckle** but I don't know how to start i google it many times but no result, I am newbie so can someone give me some good source how to do that?

this is how swagger UI looks like.

[image]

Comment: why you want to retrieve data from swagger? you can already retrieve data from your api! swagger is for your api test and documentation purpose. If I have misunderstand some thing please clarify.

Comment: If I get it clearly, this api is not written by me, other company wrote and they give URL to me, now I am trying refer this api with c#

Comment: What swagger telling you is you have 5 methods to post and 1 method to delete, you need to expand your api with GET to reterive the data, so If you do not know that you need to start reading a bit and understand what is this about.

Comment: I didn't find where i can read, there are only source how can I create swagger api witch c#, but I need how to retrieve from swagger web-service

Comment: maybe I missed some points?

Comment: swagger is not responsible for api, you can have api with out swagger. Swagger job is just to see your api and create these links as documentation and for testing purpose. so for instance you suppose to have a controller in your code that has a post method, there you could create a get method to retrieve the data, then you need in that method to define where the data comes from and what data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189811/discussion-between-vaso-miruashvili-and-maytham-mahtyam).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Example above page I can see when I run API. In SwaggerConfig.cs there got EnableSwaggerUi section try to find RoutePrefix add string.empty so that you can see swagger page directly if can't find this try to add /swagger next to port number then you see swagger home page